# fb:registration plugins permissions

Tags: php, facebook, permissions, registration

I am new to facebook registration plugins.  I implemented the dummy code for registration form given on the facebook developers website.  But when i signed up throught this registration form.  It gives the permission for offline access, send an email, user_about_me.  Is it possible to give any specific permissions for this registration forms?

```
<fb:registration redirect-uri="http://developers.facebook.com/tools/echo"    
 fields='[ {"name":"name"},
   {"name":"foo","description":"Type foo","type":"text"},
{"name":"bar","description":"Type bar","type":"text"},
{"name":"facebooker","description":"Pick Paul","type":"select","options":
 {"coder":"Paul","pm":"Austin","partners":"Cat"}},
{"name":"check","description":"Check this","type":"checkbox"},
{"name":"date","description":"Dec 16 2010","type":"date"},
{"name":"city","description":"Calgary","type":"typeahead","categories":
  ["city"]}]' 
onvalidate="validate"></fb:registration>
```

code i used from [facebook registration page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/advanced/)

Comment: @genesis:  i have attached the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fields="name,birthday,gender,location,email"
```

--

```
<fb:registration 
  fields="name,birthday,gender,location,email" 
  redirect-uri="http://developers.facebook.com/tools/echo/"
  width="530">
</fb:registration>
```

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/

and list of permissions: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/

Comment: so can i define the permissions in fields?

Comment: i don't think it will work as fields provides a way to define a text boxes in the registration form.

Comment: I know, but known fields are created and ALSO FILLED

Comment: is there any way i can get more user information through different permissions?

Comment: that's the only reference from FB http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/

Answer (score 0):

If you need permissions above and beyond the available fields, you need to redirect the user to the OAuth dialog with the scope params set correctly.

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/